# Can't run NvChad on my Nvim, E5113, module 'lazy' not found

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

Can't run NvChad on my Nvim, E5113, module 'lazy' not found

Hello,

I spent all the afternoon on Nvim. Starting point was my macBook Pro from mid 2010 which was blocked in mac OS 10.12 (Sierra). Impossible to install Nvim on this OS. So i tried to force Ventura (last Mac OS) on my macBook with Open-Core Patcher which is a success.
So now I install Nvim and I'm looking for plugins. I found NvChad which seems to be good so why not.

I have Nvim 0.9.0 and I simply copy paste this line in my ~ folder :
git clone https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad ~/.config/nvim --depth 1 && nvim

It works, but when Nvim starts, I have this error and I tried absolutely everything I could think and find of :
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLESH.png)

I saw some people just delete the ~/.local/share/nvim, launch again Nvim and it works, not for me

If anyone has an idea of what should I do it would be great !

Thx for reading